# How to force Jackson to close an empty XML element?

Tags: xml, serialization, jackson

I'm trying to serialize simple objects to XML using Jackson but I'm having trouble closing empty XML elements.
I get this

```
<SimplePojo name="simpleName">
</SimplePojo>
```

but I want this

```
<SimplePojo name="simpleName"/>
```

If there's a setting for it, I can't find it.
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

---

```java
public class SimplePojo
{
    public SimplePojo(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;       
    }

    @JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true)
    private String name;

    public String getName()
    {
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setName(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @JsonInclude(Include.NON_EMPTY) 
    private String property;

    public String getProperty()
    {
        return property;
    }

    public void setProperty(String property)
    {
        this.property = property;
    }
}
```

and I'm using the class like this:

```java
 JacksonXmlModule module = new JacksonXmlModule();
    module.setDefaultUseWrapper(false);

    XmlMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper(module); 
    xmlMapper.configure(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT, true);
    SimplePojo simple = new SimplePojo("simpleName");
    //simple.setProperty("something");

    String res = xmlMapper.writeValueAsString(simple);
```

**EDIT:**
Here is a list of the jars I'm using

[image: Jackson jars]

Answer (score 1):

I also came across this issue using both 2.3.1 and 2.2.3 versions of `jackson-data-format-xml`. Managed to resolve it by adding the same `Woodstox` jars as you. So pretty sure the fix isn't indentation related.

If you are not sure if you are using `Woodstox`, you explicitly create a woodstox `XMLFactory` and use it in your `XMLMapper`

```
XmlFactory xmlFactory = new XmlFactory(new WstxInputFactory(), new WstxOutputFactory());
XmlMapper mapper = new XmlMapper (xmlFactory, module);
```

Good luck!

Comment: in my case only adding library to classpath did not make jackson use the woodstox library, but generating mapper from factory did. thx!

Answer (score 0):

One possible thing to try is to make sure you use `Woodstox` as your Stax implementation and NOT the default one JDK provides (Sun's SJSXP). Woodstox is better all-around, and I think it also implicitly uses empty elements if possible, whereas SJSXP I think does not.

Comment: I added a pic of my dependencies. I think I'm using Woodstox behind the scene (without the jar I get exceptions)

Comment: Ok thanks. You do use all the recommended pieces then. I vaguely recall a request wrt empty elements earlier... need to check out project issue tracker to remember details. This should be doable, FWIW.

Comment: are you referring to this:https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformat-xml/issues/45

Comment: Probably. Unit test for issue #45 does actually verify that empty element is used if there is no character content. Maybe I can reproduce issue you are having.

Comment: Oh. The problem is indentation: if you force indentation, linefeed is added. If not, empty element would be output. It is hard to say if this can be changed (indentation logic may not have enough information to know what, if anything, to do), but perhaps this could be improved.